# What's the best way to get from Freiburg (Germany) to Hannover (Germany)?

Tags: budget, transportation, germany

What's the best way to get from Freiburg to Hannover in October? I mean *fast, safe and cheap* by best.

How long does it take, approximately?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard way would be to take a train. The [German railways site](http://bahn.de/) is the place to look for train schedules and prices, and you can book online and print most ticket types at home. The website normally shows the fastest routes only, but you can tell it to omit ICEs (high-speed trains, often more expensive) or to stick to regional trains (slowest and usually cheapest).

The bad news about German rail prices is that they are very complicated. The good news is that the DB trip planner will *usually* offer you the cheapest price for a given connection. The exception is that sometimes a day ticket is cheaper even for a single trip, and the website won't always tell you. Generally speaking, you will get a substantial discount if you decide on a day and time early and book a non-refundable, non-exchangeable ticket. These tickets can often give you high-speed travel for a similar price as regional trains. Some ticket types also include the possibility of local travel (buses, trams, U-Bahn, S-Bahn) at the beginning or end of the journey, check if it's a possibility (it's rarely a deciding factor in choosing a fare type).

At the moment, the cheapest fare I can see in October is 44€ for a high-speed connection (direct, or ICE most of the way with one change),
if you avoid the heaviest-loaded peak hour trains, for a 4½ to 5 hours journey time. Alternatively, you can pay 42€ for a ticket that lets you travel on all regional trains in Germany for a day provided you start after 9am ([Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket](http://www.bahn.de/p/view/angebot/regio/qdl.shtml)). Do note that Freiburg to Hannover is 10 hours on regional trains.

If several of you are traveling on the same route, note that some ticket types offer considerable discounts for additional passengers. For example, the Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket is only 6€ for each additional passenger traveling together. The [Schönes Wochenende Ticket](http://www.bahn.de/i/view/GBR/en/prices/germany/schoenes_wochenende_ticket.shtml), valid for one day on a Saturday or Sunday in regional trains only, is 39€ for up to 5 people. Thus one possibility for cheap travel is to find someone who's taking the same train anyway and offer to pay the add-on price. I don't foresee this working well for a cross-country journey like yours though.

Sometimes you can get cheap fares on budget airlines. These are often only attractive if you have a cheap way to get to and from the airport; otherwise the cost of local transportation can be prohibitive. There's no airport near Freiburg; the closest is the [Basel/Mulhouse/Freiburg EuroAirport](http://www.euroairport.com/), and a bus ticket to Freiburg is a whooping [22€](http://www.freiburger-reisedienst.de/en/airportbus/fares.php).

If you don't take the train and don't fly, your other option is to hitch-hike. That can come out cheapest, if you find someone going the right way at the right time.

---

If you're traveling from the [Basel/Mulhouse/Freiburg EuroAirport](http://www.euroairport.com/), the situation is quite different. Flying might be more attractive, though for this particular combination of cities it doesn't seem to be: you can't fly direct to Hannover, only to Hamburg, and [Easyjet](http://www.easyjet.com/)'s cheapest fare comes out at 41€ (including the booking fees in small type).

The best train route is via Basel (which you can [reach](http://www.euroairport.com/EN/voyageurs.php?PAGEID=488&lang=EN) by a [relatively cheap (4€)](http://www.bvb.ch/en/tickets-fares/standard-fares/single-tickets) [local bus](http://www.bvb.ch/en/timetable-network/haltestellenfahrplan?50)); this requires going through Switzerland (which may be a problem for some visa types). (While there are both an SNCF (French railways) station (Basel/Bâle SNCF) and a DB (German railways) station (Basel Bad Bf) in Basel, they are separated by a few hundred meters of Switzerland. The SNCF station is next to the Swiss railway station, Basel SBB. Since Switzerland has joined [Shengen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Agreement), border checks are no longer systematic and Shengen visas are valid.)

At this time, the 44€ rate from Basel Bad to Hannover is available if you travel near the middle of the day. Book early, as prices will rise towards the standard fare (119€) as the travel day approaches. Many discount rates are also valid from Basel SBB (which is where the bus from the airport drops you). There's also a discount rate for international tickets from and to Germany, [Europa-Spezial](http://www.bahn.com/i/view/GBR/en/prices/europe/europa-spezial.shtml), but I'm not sure if it's available from Basel. There's a direct night train as well; it's more expensive than the day train but can be less expensive than the day train plus a night in a hostel.

If you need to avoid Switzerland, take a bus to Saint-Louis then French regional trains to Mulhouse and on to Strasbourg. You can look up the times, but not book, on the [DB website](http://bahn.de/) (Saint-Louis is “St-Louis(Haut Rhin)”). You can look up times and prices on the [French regional trains website](http://www.ter-sncf.com/Regions/Commun/Navigation.aspx?page=Accueil) (French only as far as I can see); there are no discounts for advance purchase on regional trains, so buy your ticket when you arrive at the station.

Comment: Actually, I want to get from the Basel/Mulhouse/Freiburg EuroAirport to Hannover.. is it the same? and thanks a lot for your complete answer.

Comment: @Gigili Euroairport to Hannover is very different from Freiburg to Hannover! Hitch-hiking is a lot harder. Flying is more attractive. If you take the train, going via Saint-Louis or Basel (Basel requires a Swiss visa if applicable) will probably be cheaper, as Freiburg is a lot further from the airport. You can look up and book trains from Saint-Louis to Basel on the DB website.

Comment: Really? I needed to know how to get to Hannover from Freiburg airport!

Comment: @Gigili Euroairport is really the Basel airport; it's called Freiburg airport because Freiburg is the closest major *German* city and the airport is financed by the three countries. Most discount fares are the same from Basel to Hannover or from Freiburg to Hannover, but going from the airport to the station is a lot cheaper with Basel. See my updated answer.

Comment: Note that Sparpreis tickets are refundable (for an EUR 15 fee) before the day they are valid for.

Comment: There aren't a lot of visas that would allow you to go to France and Germany but not through Switzerland.

Answer (score 7):

As @iHaveacomputer already said, you could consider using a  *Mitfahrgelegenheit*, a form of car-sharing.

At the moment, this is by far the cheapest way to travel in Germany.

People planning to drive to a certain place at a certain time announce that on the Internet; people looking for a ride to that place contact them, and ride along.

There are two major web players on the *Mitfahrgelegenheiten* market:

- [mitfahrgelegenheit.de](http://mitfahrgelegenheit.de)
- [mitfahrzentrale.de](http://mitfahrzentrale.de)

mitfahrgelegenheit.de does not charge community members for contact information; it is available immediately, and publicly. That makes it the superior choice IMO.

In contrast, mitfahrzentrale.de's business model is to charge the seeker looking to contact drivers. For payment, you either call a premium telephone number (charging €1.86 a minute at the time of writing; I do not know how many minutes it takes to get hold of the data.) or pay through bank payment. Both options may not be available to you as a traveler.

Using a Mitfahrgelegenheit is not always a 100% reliable business. Appointments are usually made by E-Mail or phone, and sometimes, people will simply not show up - although naturally, the drivers usually do.  Mitfahrgelegenheit.de is offering a booking and payment system that allows for reliable reservations, but the vast majority of rides is still worked out by phone.

Still, this is a very cheap and potentially pleasant way to travel the country and get in touch with some locals - the ride you are looking for averages at between 25 and 35 Euros. The regular high-speed train fare (without advance reservation and special deals) is about 113 Euros. There are cheaper train options, but they usually entail excruciatingly long travel times on crappy trains with lots of changeovers.

Comment: Good point. I just recently used it and drove from Prague (Czech Republic) to Lake Constance (Germany). It was about 700 km, took 7 hours with some short stops and I just payed 20 Euro. Really cheap! Additionally, I was able to carry two big bagpacks with me!

Answer (score 6):

Fast and safe would be the train, however this is not exactly cheap unless you have a "Bahn Card". For fast and cheap try http://www.mitfahrzentrale.de/ . I would say it's pretty safe, since people in Germany don't carry that many weapons anymore since 1945, however some people tend to be unreliable, or late... even in Germany :)

I think that are you only 2 options that make sense if you don't have a car; there is no long distance overland bus system like greyhound in Germany.

Comment: In Germany there are lots of slower local trains you can take to save money but I don't know hot to figure out the connections. Personally I love Mitfahrzentrale and have used it on my last two trips to Europe. Cheaper than trains and buses and thanks to the lack of speed limits on the Autobahn can be very fast. Both of my trips were in Mercedes so were also very comfortable. I think I paid 30 euro for Berlin-Munich two years ago and for Frankfurt-Berlin last year.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, Die Deutsche Bahn, or Mitfahrgelegenheit is probably the cheapest option.

But for the sake of completness I want to mention [Eurolines](http://www.touring.de/). It is a coach company that connects all big cities in whole Europe. I personally used it for example to travel from Tallinn to St. Petersburg. It is relatively cheap, reliable and comfortable. The coaches are generally in a good form.

There are also some connection that travel between different German cities.

Comment: +1. Legislation from the Weimar Republic designed to protect the railway monopoly is still stifling any attempts to build a serious long-distance bus network in Germany, but the international lines may sometimes work for you - however, as far as I know, they are forbidden to offer city-to-city connections within the country.

Comment: To be honest, I never ever heard of that, but it is really interesting. And yes, there are only a few long distance buses in Germany, but if you are lucky you can find one that meets your requirements.

Comment: yeah. If I wrote down what should be done to the political class for keeping this law enacted for 80 years, I would probably get a visit from the *Verfassungsschutz*. (Hint: It would involve a flamethrower. Or tar and feathers.)

Comment: There are certainly overland bus connections between German cities. The standard prices are cheaper than trains, but they don't have many special offers and often take longer than trains.